# Turn off formatter for some lines when using Eclipse Formatter plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, eclipse-formatter

Is there any way to specify to say that these lines should not be formatted when using the Eclipse Formatter plugin in Android Studio?

`//@formatter:off` and `//@formatter:on` do not work for me

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the Eclipse formatter plugin in Studio, but you can enable those tags by going to 
**File -> Settings -> Code Style -> General** and there at the bottom you'll find "**Enable formatter markers in comments**"

Comment: Does not work for me. The reason could be that I am using the Eclipse Formatter plugin to format my Code though.